# unexpected keyword argument in tensorflow object-detection api

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am following this tutorial: https://pythonprogramming.net/introduction-use-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/  to do object detection on my own dataset and finetune the pre-trained model.

when I run this command:

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "train.py", line 51, in <module>

    from object_detection import trainer

  File "/Users/apple/Downloads/models/research/object_detection/trainer.py", line 27, in <module>

    from object_detection.builders import preprocessor_builder

  File "/Users/apple/Downloads/models/research/object_detection/builders/preprocessor_builder.py", line 21, in <module>

    from object_detection.protos import preprocessor_pb2

  File 
"/Users/apple/Downloads/models/research/object_detection/protos/preprocessor_pb2.py", line 71, in <module>

    options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file'
```

and removing this argument does not solve this issue.

I am using macosx 10.12.6 - sierra

Any help?

Comment: Any fixes on this? I'm experiencing the same problem...

Comment: I was using python 3.5 and got many exceptions, but it works with python 2.7

Comment: I have compiled the protos to .py files but I don't see the argument file=DESCRIPTOR. Tensorflowversion_1.8.0 Python_3.6.5 Windows.. i dont see any error when I execute the code